# Timer in reusable code in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, signals

I am writing a multi-threaded application. One of the threads needs to do some work periodically, so I use `setitimer` to set up a timer and have `SIGALRM` sent to the process when the timer expires.

The problem is that I do not know beforehand which of the threads will receive the signal.

This could be easily solved by setting signal masks for each thread so that only one thread may receive `SIGALRM`. But that does not seem appropriate in this particular case, because the timer is registered in one of the modules of the application which are meant for use in other programs, too. (As a shared piece of code. It's a communication wrapper for certain kind of a special USB device.)

The suggested (and standard) approach would require the user of this code to either

- Be aware of the problem and set signal masks correctly when spawning the threads, or
- Set the timer himself/herself and call some special handler in the module discussed above when the timer expires.

And that doesn't seem right.

What would be a common solution to a situation in which one piece of reusable code requires a timer to operate, which may potentially interfere with the operation of the rest of the program?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a timer/SIGALRM?  Can you use a sleep() loop or a timed wait on some other synchro that willl not have implications or side-effects on other modules?

Comment: I can use pretty much anything I want, with the exception of busy-waiting. What do you mean precisely by "a timed wait on some other synchro"? Thanks!

Comment: Something like pthread_cond_timedwait() or sem_timedwait().  Isolated, self-contained, no CPU-sucking busy-wait.

Comment: Please give me a sec, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Have an upvote anyway.  I hate external effects/dependencies.  One reason to use threads is to develop sub-systems, with their own execution, that I can just bolt-on to apps and they will work without fiddling around with the other stuff that already works and I don't want to change.

Comment: So it's maybe *your* frustration I'm trying to avoid by carefully designing *my* code? Funny :). Anyway, it seems I would have to use `pthread_cond_timedwait` with a fake mutex and fake condition variable to delay further processing of the thread that does the periodical work, right? It seems a little like a misuse of the POSIX threads API, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pthread_kill` which let you signal a given thread. You can then use a daemon thread that calls `sleep` and `pthread_kill` in a controlled loop to clock your given thread.

If you care about global process timers interactions with sleep, then you can use `usleep` (or `nanosleep`).

Comment: I think I should not call sleep in a "daemon thread" as this may be implemented using `SIGALRM` according to the manpage. I would be interfering with global state of the process, which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place. Nonetheless, thanks for help.

Comment: That solves my problem. And it's so simple after all. Thanks a lot and please accept my condolences regarding the misfortune in Paris.